# How was this invisible space created?

Tags: string

```
'{FileTitle​}' === '{FileTitle}'
// false
```

There's a space between the first string's last `e` and `}`

```
'{FileTitle​}'.length
// 12

'{FileTitle}'.length
// 11
```

Comment: Where do you see that space??

Comment: I don't see it but it's there. Try copying and pasting into console, then move your cursor from left to right, and if I'm making it up.. why is this false?

Comment: Can you show the rest of code ?

Comment: What code? this is it.

Comment: If this is some particular programming language, please add a tag to indicate which one. If it isn't, this question probably belongs on another site, perhaps http://superuser.com/

Comment: Now you know what the character is.  Now can you tell us how it got there?

Comment: This was discovered by a colleague in a .NET application, but I pasted the code JavaScript so that it could be easily tested in the browser console. I don't know for sure, but I think this came from a parsed JSON response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is Unicode character with code 8203 between those two characters.  This is a 0-width space.  Have a look at the corresponding [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) for more info.

Comment: Man that is wicked dangerous. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: How did you identify `8203`? I see `0B20`, but am not sure if my way to copy it out was the right one :-)

Comment: @peter_the_oak hit "edit" on the question, copy the full string in question - paste it into excel - and then use `code` function in another cell to get the code of the 11th char in the string.

Comment: @Aleks G: great idea, thx. In the meantime, I got some help and could correct my answer, so there are now two ways to see the special char correctly. BTW, we could even simplier just chose "Inspect Element" from the browser; e.g. Chrome notes and highlights directly the entity `&#8203;`  :-)

Answer (score 2):

This is a great example of a sometimes nasty problem :-)

If I copy your code to TextWrangler, then I see the space. If I chose "Hex Dump", then I see the hex bytes 0B 20. Considering the little endian context (thx to @axiac), this means the character 0x200B, decimal 8203.

[image]

For informations about specific unicode characters, use this: http://unicode-table.com/de/search/?q=8203 You'll see the description "Zero Width Space".

About how this character got into your code, one can only guess. Option one is, you wrote it in your editor unwittingly by hitting a certain key combination. Option two is, you copied it from a rich text document as a stowaway. Option three is, it got there because of some stumbled multibyte string operation.

A related problem is Ascii `0xA0` (or `0x00A0`), the non-breakable space. It cannot be distinguished from a normal space by eye, but causes compiler syntax errors sometimes hard to resolve.

Comment: It is `200B`, not `0B20`. Notice that the other characters are encoded using the [little endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Little-endian) byte order (the least significant byte first). And `0x200B` is exactly `8023` when represented in decimal.

Comment: @axiac, thank you very much for pointing out little endian. I completely forgot about this for a moment here... I've corrected my answer.

Answer (score -1):

This one has no space 
'{FileTitle}' === '{FileTitle}'

You just used different encoding.