# C++ Trouble overloading operators in a template class

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

Every time I add comments inside the definitions of the operators, it starts giving me errors, but removing the comments immediately gets rid of the errors. I don't see why comments would have any effect at all on the code. Also just general advice on the overloading of operators in general would be appreciated.

Heres my class template:

```
template<class THING>
struct LLNode
{
  THING data;
  LLNode<THING> *next;
  LLNode<THING> *prev;
};
template<class THING>
class LinkedList
{
private:
     //use a doubly linked-list based implementation
     //keep a head and tail pointer for efficiency
     LLNode<THING> *Head;
     LLNode<THING> *Tail;
     int count;
public:
     //setup initial conditions
     LinkedList();
     //delete all dynamic memory, etc.
     ~LinkedList();
     //constant bracket operator to access specific element
     const THING& operator[](int);
     //Bracket operator to access specific element
     THING& operator[](int);
     //Equality operator to check if two lists are equal
     bool operator==(const LinkedList<THING>&);
     //Inequality operator to check if two lists are equal
     bool operator!=(const LinkedList<THING>&);
     //add x to front of list
     void addFront(THING);
     //add x to back of list
     void addBack(THING);
     //add x as the ith thing in the list
     //if there are less than i things, add it to the back
     void add(THING, int);
     //remove and return front item from list
     THING removeFront();
     //remove and return back item from list
     THING removeBack();
     //return value of back item (but don't remove it)
     THING getBack();
     //return value of front item (but don't remove it)
     THING getFront();
     //return how many items are in the list
     int length();
     //print all elements in the linked list
     void print();
};
```

And the operators I'm currently working on:

```
template<class THING>
THING& LinkedList<THING>::operator[](int index)
{

}

template<class THING>
bool LinkedList<THING>::operator==(const LinkedList<THING>& list_one, const LinkedList<THING>& list_two)
{
    //checking for same size on both lists
    //if both are same size, move on to checking for same data
    if(list_one.count != list_two.count)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        //boolean flag to hold truth of sameness
        bool flag = true;
        //two pointers to go through
        LLNode<THING> *temp_one = list_one.Head;
        LLNode<THING> *temp_two = list_two.Head;
        while(temp_one != NULL && temp_two != NULL)
        {
            if(temp_one->data != temp_two->data)
            {
                flag = false;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                temp_one = temp_one->next;
                temp_two = temp_two->next;
            }
        }
        return flag;
    }
}
```

Comment: How can we help when you don't specify which comments cause the error and the error message?

Comment: Avoid identifiers in all caps, as they are conventionally used for macros. Pass your thing by const reference where possible to avoid copies.

Comment: Well I said "comments inside the definitions of the operators" so like "//checking for same size on both lists..." for example makes the following if statement say "error:expected declaration" and "//boolean flag to hold..." makes a bunch of things in that else statement get underlined red

Comment: Can you provide a self-contained code sample that we can compile which reproduces the error.

Comment: I haven't even tried compiling it, the errors just show up on the code as red lines underlining certain identifiers.

Comment: Now it is clear. You are using Visual Studio and those red lines are intellisense errors. Intellisense errors take a while to update after code changes and I disable it as it is too annoying

Comment: Try to find out if just One of several comments makes troubles. Then, find out if there is a rich text char in that comment. See here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28842986/how-was-this-invisible-space-created/28843327#28843327](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28842986/how-was-this-invisible-space-created/28843327#28843327)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These, as you've said, aren't compilation errors: they are Intellisense errors. These errors take a while to refresh in the extension and therefore aren't very indicative most of the time, and it's a known issue that Intellisense isn't great with adding comments, and is even worse when colliding with other extensions.

One way to get rid of the errors is to cut-paste all of the code (just go *ctrl+a, ctrl+x, ctrl+v*). This forces Intellisense to refresh.

Another way which is a personal favorite of mine is to shut down Intellisense :) you can see how to do that [in here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ecfczya1%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: You were right, I just finished writing the code and it compiled even though the Intellisense errors are still showing up.
How would I shut down Intellisense ?